# Reading words and counting their occurence in Java

Tags: java, performance, io

I have very typical problem:

Given big text file, containing text. The task is to calculate occurence of each word and print this info from most occured to less.

Example input:

```
cat cat cat dog dog mouse
```

Correct answer:

```
cat -> 3
dog -> 2
mouse -> 1
```

First I solved this using `Scanner`. But this solutions seems to be slow, cause IO was blocking.

After some time and cookie spent I wrote this solution:

```java
final Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/tmp/", "file.txt");

Map<String, Long> occ =
  Files
    .lines(path)
    .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(delimRegex)))
    .filter(line -> line.length() > 0)
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

occ
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue()))
  .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue()));
```

I think solution is good (but not sure). Is there any other optimization techniques I've ignored?

Answer (score 2):

I have one comment: 
[`Files.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) method has the following comment in the JDK documentation:

> The returned stream encapsulates a Reader. If timely disposal of file
>   system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should
>   be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the
>   stream operations are completed.

in other words, in order to prevent resource leak, you need to construct the stream in a try-with-resources block

```
try (Stream<String> linesStream = Files.lines(path)) {
    Map<String, Long> occ = linesStream
        .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(delimRegex)))
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One other comment about your code: variable names are not perfect:

```
  ...
  Files
    .lines(path)
    .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(delimRegex))) // OK, this is a line
    .filter(line -> line.length() > 0) // But this is a word
    ....
```

Also: consider using `String::isEmpty` instead of the lambda filter expression.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments about things that you said in the question:

> "First I solved this using Scanner. But this solutions seems to be slow, cause IO was blocking."

If you are reading from a file, I/O will not be blocking.   It is possible that Scanner is using a buffer that is too small, but I think that is unlikely.  You were probably doing something else wrong.

> "I think solution is good (but not sure). Is there any other optimization techniques I've ignored?"

Using streams is not an optimization technique.  Accepted wisdom is that using streams is currently *a bit* slower than an equivalent algorithm implemented using loops.  The real advantage of streams is that they are simpler to write and understand than old-fashioned loops, especially when the transformation is complex.  For example, you have implemented your problem with just two statements.

Not that I would rewrite your code.  It is rarely worthwhile rewriting code to get a small performance boost.  Developer time is more precious than computer time.

> "After some time and cookie spent I wrote this solution:"

Here's the real problem.  Too many cookies are bad for your health.  Black coffee with no sugar is a much better aid for programming ... and it is better for your waistline and your teeth :-)